# You can’t delete this record choice set yet. Remove all references to the record choice set, and try again

Tags: community, visual-workflow, account, delete, screen-flow

You can’t delete this record choice set yet. Remove all references to the record choice set, and try again.

I am trying to delete Account from the screen flow:
[image]

No matter what I tried it does not let me delete it. It gives this message. How can I delete it?

Answer (score 0):

This means that somewhere else in your flow, you are referencing this record choice set.  Look in your assignment elements, decision elements, manual variable assignments etc.  Somewhere you are referencing it.  When you remove that reference you'll be able to delete it.